# Getting total number of streams and track release date through Spotify API

Tags: spotify, last.fm

I'm trying to get a large list of songs released in year X, together with their number of plays/streams.

I've been using Spotify API, and I have a number of highly popular songs. Now, for my purposes, I also need a list of non-popular songs (low play counts). I am wondering if there is any strategy to get a list of songs (maybe last played ones?), and extract their release year and number of total plays?

I've been going through the API documentation and I can only find 'popularity', which seems different from total number of plays. Secondly, I haven't found a way to get a list of last played songs yet. Should I be considering another type of strategy?

I know that you can get a list of recently played songs of all users in certain user groups in last.fm. Perhaps there is something similar in Spotify API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to get play counts through the Spotify API, only the Popularity metric.

Comment: what does popularity represent exactly? What is the scale?

Comment: You're probably not going to be able to find more details than the description at https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/tracks/get-track/
The developers are unlikely to offer the finer details of their algorithm.